# Oracle custom order based on previous id field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a previous id and want to sort the output based on id_prev. Null must be the first value.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPFVl.png)

**Table**

```
id | id_prev | data
------------------
1  | 2       | foo
2  | 4       | foo
3  | 1       | foobar
4  | null    | fooo
10 | 3       | fo
8  | 10      | fo
```

**Result**

```
id | id_prev | sort | data
------------------
4  | null    | 1    | fooo
2  | 4       | 2    | foo
1  | 2       | 3    | foo
3  | 1       | 4    | foobar
10 | 3       | 5    | fo
8  | 10      | 6    | fo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONNECT BY PRIOR

```
select id,id_prev,level,data 
from TABLE_NAME
start with id_prev is null
connect by prior  id=id_prev
order by level;
```

Comment: This is the right answer in my opinion - this is one of the principal uses of hierarchical queries. Note that "order by level" is not needed (at least in this example, where the entire hierarchy is linear); one of the features of hierarchical queries is that they also order the output.

Comment: Thank you. This work for me. But the perfomance seems not to be the best. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: add necessary indexes if missing CREATE INDEX IDX1 ON TABLE_NAME(ID);   CREATE INDEX IDX2 ON TABLE_NAME(ID_PREV);

Comment: @kostja7 - if performance is not satisfactory, then perhaps something is wrong with your problem. Hierarchical "connect by prior" queries have been around for some time, they are super-optimized (by Oracle); it is unlikely that you will find anything faster than this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from (
    select
      t.id,
      t.id_prev,
      t.data,
      row_number() over(order by t.id_prev DESC NULLS FIRST) AS sort
    from
      {your_table} t
) t order by t.sort;
```

Comment: Wow nice option..btw the order by should be `id_prev desc`.. Hope they bring this to `Sql Server`

Comment: This worked for the given example. But i had an other meaning. I added two rows to the example for better explanation

Comment: I don't understand. How is the ordering by `t.id_prev` going to order the rows hierarchically? Perhaps the OP's wording wasn't very clear, but the example - with desired output - is crystal clear, he is looking for hierarchical ordering of the rows. (Perhaps original post was edited after this answer was given?)

Comment: @mathguy, yep, the question's description was updated after I had posted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Order by`

```
Order by case when id_prev is null then 1 else 0 end desc,id_prev desc
```

If you want sort column in result then

```
Row_number()
     Over(Order by case when id_prev is null then 1 else 0 end desc,id_prev desc) as Sort
```

Comment: There's no need for the case expression in the order by clauses - Oracle has the NULLS (FIRST|LAST) option, and the default is NULLS LAST for ascending sorts and NULLS FIRST for descending sorts, as per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2171079)